# Why Here Sdk is not showing detailed map of Karachi, Pakistan? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, maps, heremaps

Why city Karachi of Pakistan is not showing on the map, also many details of the country are missing. I have tried zooming in and out to many other cities and they are perfectly shown.

[image: Karachi, Pakistan]